# How to set the styleclass attribute of a JSF component from bean?

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces-3

I am using Icefaces 3.2. I would like to know how to reset the styleClass attribute of a component e.g textarea from the backing bean method.

USECASE: I have an `ace:textAreaEntry` which has a validator method in the backing bean. In this backing bean I am doing some validation. If the validation fails I want a particular CSS class applied to the component. So I want to reset the value of the styleclass attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `styleClass` conditionally ,like this

```
<ace:textAreaEntry 
    styleClass="#{facesContext.validationFailed?'failedClass':'validClass'}"/>
```

or assign fail class only and otherwise no class at all

```
<ace:textAreaEntry 
    styleClass="#{facesContext.validationFailed?'failedClass':''}"/>
```

If you manually set message to be displayed in your page you can check if `facesContext.messageList` is empty or not, like this

```
<ace:textAreaEntry 
    styleClass="#{(not empty facesContext.messageList)?'filedClass':'validClass'}"/>
```

---

If you want to test for some specific internal logic validation you can check for some boolean for example

```
<ace:textAreaEntry 
    styleClass="#{(myBean.someComponentFailed)?'filedClass':'validClass'}"/>
```

where `someComponentFailed` is some property that you set to true/false upon validation failure

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but if with this approach, my styleclass of textareaentry will change even if the validation has failed because of other component. I want to check the validation  failure only for particular component.